# Convert Pandas DF of Floats to Str, Keep trailing zeros

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am attempting to convert a DataFrame of Floats, to Strings, while keeping trailing zeros at the hundredth decimal point.  Here is my function:

```
def df_formatter(df):

    cols = df.columns

    for x in cols:
        for index,cell in enumerate(df[x]):
            df.loc[:,x][index] = str('{:.2f}'.format(Decimal(df[x][index])))

    return df
```

The issue is that my dataframe is still in float format, even after applying the function. when i apply .astype(str) method to convert to strings, I lose the hundredth decimal point, if that hundredth decimal is a 0.  For example, 0.00 --> 0.0, or 0.50 --> 0.5.  This is currency and percentage data, so important to keep trailing zeros.

What is my issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if i understood correctly but I think this is a solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'floats': [0.5, 0.66, 0.]})

df['floats'] = df['floats'].apply(lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x))
print(df)

>>>
  floats
0   0.50
1   0.66
2   0.00
```

Comment: If you do not understand something or maybe i misunderstood you please let me know

Comment: No, you understood me perfectly - this works great. Thanks for solving without any need for sample data.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please include sample data for the future then people will be more eager to help you

Comment: I appreciate the advice and I will.

Comment: I logged in just to upvote and thank you @Sebatian. This was driving me crazy for the last hour. Thanks a bunch ;-)